# Django with sqlit3

Tags: python, django

I have created a blog website using python with Django, And I added database to model file, when you add blogs the blogs will be saved and anyone can see them. My question is where the database has been saved ? I downloaded sqlit browser to view the dababase but I do not know how to view them using SQLite browser.
Thanks

Comment: Please see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#s-name) on the `Django` doc. If you specify the full path there you will have control of where the `SQLite` DB will be stored.

Comment: You can use manage.py dbshell to get access to your db

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the database using `syncdb` or `makemigrations/migrations` then `db.sqlite3` should be located right in the root of the app, same directory as `manage.py`. This is the file you want. Should look something like this:

```
    mysite/
        db.sqlite3
        manage.py
        mysite/
            __init__.py
            settings.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
```